# n-th derivative of the power rule

Tags: derivatives, summation

I've been trying to find out a general formula for $\Big(f(x)^k\Big)^{(n)}$, where $\Big(f(x)\Big)^{(n)}$ is the n-th derivative of $f(x)$ (assuming it's possible to derivate $f(x)$). I have tried using the general formula of a product $\Big(f(x)\cdot g(x)\Big)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}f^{(n-k)}(x)\cdot g^{(k)}(x)$ but i have no idea on how to continue.
Can someone help me?

Comment: This would be a special case of Faa di Bruno's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: How so? I dont want the generalized chain rule, I want the generalized power rule. I cant see how this will help me

Comment: Apply FdB with $g(x)=x^k$.....

Comment: I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)* which gives here
\begin{align*}
\left(f(x)^k\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{{j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_k=n}\atop{j_1,\ldots,j_k\geq 0}}\binom{n}{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_k}\prod_{t=1}^kf(x)^{\left(j_t\right)}
\end{align*}